Creating FCR (First Contact Resolution) within BigQuery
I am having the exact question as this person in the link below:
T-SQL How to get First Call Resolution out of this
Is there any way to translate this from T-SQL to something that is compatible with BigQuery?
I appreciate any help!
I attempted to emulate the answer to this question, but it didn't want to work out for me when creating the subquery portion. It states to use Outer Apply, but I can't seem to use the same thing

I'd just use a window function to check a call's entry time against the following call's entry time. No need for either joins or correlated queries...
with
  your_table as 
(
  select 1 id,'Phone1' PhoneNumber,cast('2024-07-21 12:00:00' as datetime) entrytime -- as timestamp) EntryTime
  union all
  select 2 id,'Phone2',cast('2024-07-21 12:10:00' as datetime) -- timestamp)
  union all
  select 3 id,'Phone3',cast('2024-07-22 12:10:00' as datetime) --  as timestamp)
  union all
  select 4 id,'Phone1',cast('2024-07-21 18:10:00' as datetime) -- as timestamp)
  union all
  select 5 id,'Phone2',cast('2024-07-22 12:11:00' as datetime) --  as timestamp)
),
  look_ahead AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LEAD(EntryTime) OVER (
      PARTITION BY PhoneNumber
          ORDER BY EntryTime
    )
      AS NextEntryTime
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN 
    DATE_ADD(EntryTime, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    >
    NextEntryTime
  THEN
    0
  ELSE
    1
  END
    AS FirstCallResolution
FROM
  look_ahead




id
PhoneNumber
entrytime
NextEntryTime
FirstCallResolution




1
Phone1
2024-07-21 12:00:00
2024-07-21 18:10:00
0


4
Phone1
2024-07-21 18:10:00
null
1


2
Phone2
2024-07-21 12:10:00
2024-07-22 12:11:00
1


5
Phone2
2024-07-22 12:11:00
null
1


3
Phone3
2024-07-22 12:10:00
null
1



fiddle

See example.
This query do not have specific join's.
Time function can be easily adopted for BQ.
with data as(
  select 1 id,'Phone1' PhoneNumber,cast('2024-07-21 12:00:00' as datetime) entrytime -- as timestamp) EntryTime
  union all
  select 2 id,'Phone2',cast('2024-07-21 12:10:00' as datetime) -- timestamp)
  union all
  select 3 id,'Phone3',cast('2024-07-22 12:10:00' as datetime) --  as timestamp)
  union all
  select 4 id,'Phone1',cast('2024-07-21 18:10:00' as datetime) -- as timestamp)
  union all
  select 5 id,'Phone2',cast('2024-07-22 12:11:00' as datetime) --  as timestamp)
)

-- query
select *
  ,case when exists (select PhoneNumber from data t2 
  where t2.phonenumber=t1.phonenumber
    and t2.entrytime>t1.entrytime
-- this code specific for DBMS
 --   and t2.entrytime<(t1.entrytime + interval '24 hour') -- posgresql
 --  and t2.entrytime<dateadd(hour,24,t1.entrytime) -- SQL Server
    and t2.entrytime<datetime_add(t1.entrytime, interval 24 hour) -- Big Query
    )
  then 0
  else 1
  end FCR
from data t1;

Demo

@MatBailie, you right. Thank you. Corrected.

Shortest query ( same as @MatBailie ).
with data as(
  select 1 id,'Phone1' PhoneNumber,cast('2024-07-21 12:00:00' as datetime) entrytime -- as timestamp) EntryTime
  union all
  select 2 id,'Phone2',cast('2024-07-21 12:10:00' as datetime) -- timestamp)
  union all
  select 3 id,'Phone3',cast('2024-07-22 12:10:00' as datetime) --  as timestamp)
  union all
  select 4 id,'Phone1',cast('2024-07-21 18:10:00' as datetime) -- as timestamp)
  union all
  select 5 id,'Phone2',cast('2024-07-22 12:11:00' as datetime) --  as timestamp)
)
-- query
select *
  ,case when lead(entrytime)over(partition by phonenumber order by entrytime)
     <datetime_add(entrytime, interval 24 hour)
     then 0
  else 1
  end FCR
from data t1;


The wording is ambiguous in the original T-SQL question, and can be read one of 2 ways:

Time between first and second call only (if there even is a second
call), and set FCR as 1 or 0 accordingly, If less that 24 hours elapse, then set as 1.
Time between each call, which to my mind, is not first contact resolution, using the explanation here, i.e. if it is not resolved in the first call, (i.e. there are ANY subsequent calls, regardless of the timeframe), then set 0.

To answer using (1) above:
WITH mytable AS (
    SELECT '(321) 546-7842' as PhoneNumber, DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) AS EntryTime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '(321) 546-7842', DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '(251) 546-9442', DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
),

first_call AS (
    SELECT 
        PhoneNumber,
        MIN(EntryTime) AS EntryTime
    FROM
        mytable
    GROUP BY
        PhoneNumber
),

min_next_call AS (
    SELECT 
        a.PhoneNumber,
        MIN(b.EntryTime) as nextcall
    FROM
        mytable a
            INNER JOIN mytable b
                ON a.PhoneNumber = b.PhoneNumber
                AND b.EntryTime > a.EntryTime
    GROUP BY 
        a.PhoneNumber
)

SELECT
    a.*,
    b.nextcall,
    CASE
        WHEN DATETIME_DIFF(b.nextcall, a.EntryTime, HOUR) <=24 THEN 1 --check if nextcall was within (and including) 24 hours
        WHEN b.PhoneNumber IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 0
    END AS FCR
FROM
    first_call AS a 
        LEFT JOIN min_next_call AS b
            ON a.PhoneNumber = b.PhoneNumber

Result



PhoneNumber
EntryTime
nextcall
FCR




(321) 546-7842
2024-07-21T09:53:14.127578
2024-07-21T12:23:14.127578
1


(251) 546-9442
2024-07-21T10:53:14.127578
null
0




Using , for joins has been superceded by ANSI-92 join syntax for over Three Decades.

So deprecated that when I first started coding SQL in 1999 it was no longer supported? Or now in 2024? When it still works? Do you want an answer that works or an answer where respondents get hung up on semantics? Does it run? Did you answer the question with a working solution? No you did not. There are many ways to answer this, and many syntaxes that are equally valid, old or new. It doesn't make the answer wrong. You just don't like that I use and continue to use ANSI-92 syntax, which IS still supported and works. I have been coding SQL for 25 years. It doesn't mean it is wrong.

Your answer doesn't work. The original question looked forward 24 hours from each call, not the first call ever made by each number. Your answer also has numerous unnecessary self joins. As for coding for 25 years, so have I, but an appeal to expertise is a logical fallacy. As for answering the question with a working answer, yes I did.

Hi MatBailie. I amended my response to explicit joins. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. That said, it isn't clear to me that in the origin T-SQL question, nor the question above, that the requirement was to iterate over each row and check  against the next chronological instance of that number to see that EACH subsequent response was within 24h. With your understanding of the question, yes you nailed it. Kudos. With my understanding of the question, that works. The question is ambiguous, IMO.

Method is...if "number 1" didn't callback in 24 hours, then "FCR = 1". If number 2 called back within next 24 hours, then "FCR = 0" That's also how the accepted answer implemented it, which the OP is trying to replicate. It's a standard call center metric, to monitor the rate at which the agents resolve a customer call the first time (without a call back to follow up).

Which I still read as: If number 1 "(555) 111-1111" didn't call back in 24 hours, then "FCR = 1". If number 2 "(555) 222-2222" called back within next 24 hours, then "FCR = 0". Number 1 and Number 2 are not the same number. If it has said If number 1 "(555) 111-1111" didn't call back in 24 hours, then "FCR = 1". If number 1 "(555) 111-111" called again, this time within next 24 hours, then "FCR = 0" that would be what you are saying. But that is NOT what they said. The issue lies in the question, so we have different answers, to 2 different understandings of the question.

Except that the answer was accepted. Making it implicitly "per call". Also, having worked in call centre BI / Operations, I'm hugely confident of what FCR's intentions are.

If the question has a requirement for "implied" in it, it is not a good question. The OP didn't specify it. We can't all have call centre ops experience and know what the OP meant, not what they said. Well done for working it out. Like I said, kudos.
